# classifier equivalent on custom maven plugins

Tags: scala, maven, gradle, maven-plugin

I have a project with a Scala core library, a maven plug-in, a gradle plug-in and a bunch of other bits that are not needed for this question. It is built using gradle. (It seems easier to build a maven plug-in using gradle than a gradle plug-in using maven)

Due to Scala versions and compatibility different projects using the maven plug-in need different builds of the core library. Currently I need to build against 2.11.7 and 2.12.1. The core library can be solved with classifiers quite easily. E.G :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.catapult.sa</groupId>
    <artifactId>tribble-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <classifier>2.11.7</classifier>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

However maven plugin config does not have classifiers so we can't do:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.catapult.sa</groupId>
    <artifactId>tribble-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <classifier>2.11.7</classifier> <!-- this errors with Unrecognised tag: 'classifier'-->
    <configuration>...</configuration>
</plugin>
```

The code for both versions of the maven plug-in is exactly the same it just has slightly different dependencies.  The code in core is also exactly the same but built against different compilers.

I can handle this manually with a setting in the build, changing the artifactId of the maven plugin, and building twice, but is that the "right" way to solve this problem? Is there a better way or more automate-able way?

Answer (score -1):

Classifiers can be added at the execution configuration level, an example:

```
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>pre-process-classes</id>
          <phase>compile</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>jar</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <classifier>pre-process</classifier> <!-- here -->
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
```

it's a bit buried in the detail of the [POM reference](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugins) in fact the example above is from the [PluginManagement](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management) section but the principles are the same. 
This should allow you to target for each version of build you require without having to set the artifactid manually.